# How to replace placeholders inside dictionary with some values present in some other dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, templates, jinja2

I hv a dictionary named as config:

config:

```
{
  "label": "{{label}}",
  "order": "{{order}}",
  "visible": "{{is_visible}}",
  "items": "{{items}}"
}
```

values:

```
{
   "label": "Some text here!",
   "order": 23,
   "is_visible": True,
   "items": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

final Output should be:

Output:

```
{
  "label": "Some text here!",
  "order": 23,
  "visible": True,
  "items": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

**Note: Won't able to use Jinja library. because it will change the data type of every key in my output to string.**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `update` on a dict if your keys are constant, in your example they are:

```
config={
  "label": "{{label}}",
  "order": "{{order}}",
  "visible": "{{is_visible}}",
  "items": "{{items}}"
}

values={
   "label": "Some text here!",
   "order": 23,
   "visible": True,
   "items": [1,2,3,4]
}

config.update(values)
config
```

```
{'label': 'Some text here!',
 'order': 23,
 'visible': True,
 'items': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: No actually keys in config dict are not constant.

Comment: So then you need some kind of structure because `is_visible` is not the same as `visible` and if they are not constant, how would one know what `key` needs to have which `value`

Comment: yes you are right, I have updated the values dict. so placeholders inside config dict has one to one mapping in values dict.